# Selling contents of car trunk for Pesach

Tags: passover, transactions, vehicles-transportation, hotzaa-carrying-reshuyot, selling-mechirat-chametz

Would it be acceptable to put chometzdik items in the trunk of one's car, and then sell the contents of the trunk to a non-Jew before Pesach? Assume one would not open the trunk during Pesach, but would indeed drive the car.

My motivation for asking is that it seems like one would need permission to transport objects that belong to someone else, so I'd wonder if there is a special stipulation that sold items need to remain in one place during Pesach.

Comment: How about a freezer door?

Comment: http://old2.ih.chabad.info/images/notimage/32956_en_1.pdf

Comment: Since you must rent the space where the chametz is kept to the non-Jew and arrange for him to have access at all times (such as leaving the key with someone if you go away), then probably not. However, I do not have a source for this.

Comment: @GershonGold Brilliant, thanks! If you post this as an answer, I will certainly upvote

Comment: I heve heard that you can't. For the reason sabbahhillel said.. but as you suggest, perhaps if you communicate to the goy that he can access it whenever, he just has to contact you, and you won't be that far away, maybe you can meet up with him potentially.. if it's not too out of his way.  and he gives you permission to carry his stuff .. then maybe  However, generally, the rabbi sells en massre many peoples stuff to the goy, and  the goy is not going to have a special relationship with you, probably won't even know you so it's not that plausible.

Answer (score 1):

In the Sefer Nitei Gavriel he says you cannot do so (same reasoning as SabaHillel). However in the book Practical Guide to Mechiras Chametz (page 56, new 2017 edition) it says that you can do so (since there is information in the contract how to contact you to know where the "trunk" is located).